# If $G = \{g_1, ... , g_r\}$ is abelian and $a = g_1...g_r$ show that $a^2 = 1$.

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to show that if $G = \{g_1, ... , g_r\}$ is an abelian group and $a = g_1...g_r$ then $a^2 = 1$. But so far I have made little progress. I know that $|G| = r$ and so $g_i^r = 1$, but I am not sure how that is going to help.

Also since $G$ is abelian, $a^2 = g_1^2... g_r^2$ this seems useful but again I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The elements of $G$ can be sorted in "pairs" of inverses, although some "pairs" will have only one member.

Comment: In other words, the elements having no partner are selfinverse (they satify $m^{-1}=m$ implying $m^2=1$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a^2 = \prod_{g \in G} g \prod_{g \in G}g^{-1} = \prod_{g \in G}gg^{-1}=1$$